# Confusion about Distribution $\Bbb{P}_X$ and it's associating Distribution function $F$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The setup is as follows:

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \Bbb{P})$ be a probability space, and $X:\Omega\to \Bbb{R}$ be a real valued random variable. The **distribution** of $X$, $\Bbb{P}_X$, is defined as $\Bbb{P}_X = \Bbb{P}\circ X^{-1}$, and it is a probability measure on $(\Bbb{R}, \mathscr{B}(\Bbb{R}))$. We can thus associate a **distribution function**(non-decreasing, right-continuous) $\mathcal{F}_{\Bbb{P}_{X}}:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ with $\Bbb{P}_{X}$ such that
$$\mathcal{F}_{\Bbb{P}_{X}}(t) = \Bbb{P}_{X}((-\infty, t]) = \Bbb{P}(X\leq t)$$

---

My question:

Why can't we just define a distribution function $\mathcal{F}$ as $\mathcal{F}(t) = \Bbb{P}(X\leq t)$, this is still non-decreasing and right-continuous. Why do we have to go through the distribution of $\Bbb{P}_X$ to construct the distribution function $\mathcal{F}_{\Bbb{P}_X}$ when that $\mathcal{F}$ does the same thing as $\mathcal{F}_{\Bbb{P}_X}$, that is , calculating $\Bbb{P}(X\leq t)$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sure, you could avoid introducing the concept of $\Bbb{P}_X$, but does omitting this one definition actually make things simpler? I don't think so. In fact introducing $\Bbb{P}_X$ is a "natural" thing to do, because $\Omega$ is a "weird" space, while $\Bbb{R}$ is a rather nice space. Also, in measure theory, one studies Borel measures on the real line, their distribution functions etc etc, so by introducing $\Bbb{P}_X$, all the definitions you make for probability theory can be seen as special cases for things already present in measure theory.